# Array as private attribute in Python, But not its contents how to get it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, arr):
       self.__arr = arr

@property
def arr(self):
    return self.__arr
```

Now, if my purpose is to not "allow" the user of this class instance to not set a new array to arr, this does the job. For example:

```
t = Test(np.random.rand(3,3))
t.arr = np.random.rand(3,3)
```

Will raise an error: `AttributeError: can't set the attribute`

Which is what i want, BUT, if the user does the following:

```
 t = Test(np.random.rand(3,3))
 t.arr[0,0] = 1
```

No error is raised. Any tips on how to not allow the user to do that? I want the same error raise whenever any of the above happens.

Comment: Python **does not have private attributes**. Double-underscore name-mangling is **not the same thing as a private attribute**. It is to prevent name collusions on subclassing. Again, there is no privacy model in Python, everything is public.

Comment: Anyway, you can't prevent that. If the user can get access to the array, you can't stop them from mutating the array, because numpy arrays are mutable.  You could always return a copy of the internal array if you don't want any changes a user might make to that array to be reflected in the internal state of the object

Comment: A copy deffinetly does the job ! Thanks